# Cross-validation for model comparison

Tags: cross-validation, model-comparison

I have a relative big data:

more than 370,000 observations, categorical dependent variable with 250 levels，10 independent variables which including both numeric and categorical variables.

I want to perform a 10-folds cross-validation for model comparison(including classification tree model in 'rpart', svm in package 'e1071', kknn in package 'kknn', boosting and bagging in package 'adabag')

After reading the manual of these models， I try to write the codes for models performing, but I really do not know how to perform a 10-folds CV.

Actually I have tried, but I'm newly to R.
I really need help for codes or functions of the 10-folds CV.

Here is my codes:

```
w <- read.csv('D:/R code/animal2.csv',header = T)
names(w)
[1] "cluster_ward" "AAT0"         "ARIDITY"      "TOPO"         "TMAX"        
[6] "PREMAX"       "PREMIN"       "AMT"          "SU_CODE90"    "T_OC"        
[11] "ELEMAX"  

nrow(w)
[1] 370827  

w$TOPO <- as.factor(w$TOPO)
w$SU_CODE90 <- as.factor(w$SU_CODE90)  

library(rpart.plot)  
fit1 <- rpart(cluster_ward ~., w)
pred1 <- predict(fit1, w, type="class")  

library(e1071)
fit2 <-svm(cluster_ward~., data=w, kernal="sigmoid")
pred2 <- predict(a, w)

library(kknn)
set.seed(1000)
fit3 <- kknn(cluster_ward~., train=w, test=w)
pred3 <- fit3$fit

library(adabag)
set.seed(1000)
fit4 <- boosting(cluster_ward~., w)
pred4 <- predict(fit4,w)$class

library(adabag)
set.seed(1000)
fit5 <- bagging(cluster_ward~., w)
pred5 <- predict(fit5,w)$class
```

Someone has told me that package 'cvTools' or 'caret' can preform the k-folds CV, but I'm still can't perform successfully with these packages or functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually prefer to implement the CV by myself as it is relatively easy and let you have control over the algorithms you can use and the evaluation metric.

```
k = 10 # Number of k-folds
id = sample(1:k,nrow(data),replace=TRUE)
list = 1:k
for (i in 1:k){
  trainingset = subset(data, id %in% list[-i])
  testset = subset(data, id %in% c(i))

  # Training
  fit.glm = glm(cluster_ward ~ ., data=trainingset)


  # Testing
  pred = predict(fit.glm, testset, type="response")
  real = testset$cluster_ward
  rmse =  sqrt(sum((pred - real) ^ 2))/length(real)

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mingot, you have geve me great help for I'm not good at coding. It's time for learning it.

Comment: @Mingot, I don't think sample is guaranteed to give you folds with equal sizes, which I think is required by cross-validation? To quote wikipedia: "In k-fold cross-validation, the original sample is randomly partitioned into k equal size subsamples".

Comment: For a large number the difference is not important (just notice that if the number of examples is not multiple of k, you will never be able to have an equal partition).

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by kahlo is good but it doesn't give equal sized folds. Here I present my method of working

```
k = 10 # For k-folds
data$class<-sample(1:nrow(data),nrow(data),replace=FALSE)
len.data <- length(data$class)
for(i in 1:k){
    data$class[data$class <= i*len.data/k & data$class > (i-1)*len.data/k]<-i
}
list = 1:k
for (i in 1:k){
  train.set = subset(data, class %in% list[-i])
  test.set = subset(data, class %in% i))

  ## Train using train.test
  ## Test using test.set

}
```